# Эпизодически появляется ошибка System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

> System.IO.IOException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>   Additional information: Не удается прочитать данные из потока.

Ошибка появляется нерегулярно, эпизодически. 
Алгоритм следующий:

1. собираю ссылки на картинки в интернете, с этим все ОК
2. для отображения использую `ListBox`, который связан с коллекцией `ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>`

Вот метод, наполняющий коллекцию

```
/// <summary>
    /// Заполнение списка картинок
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="addresses"></param>
    private void LoadListImages(List<string> addresses)
    {
        //будущая коллекция картинок
        ListImages = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

        //to UI
        MessageUser.MessageJob.Report("Загружаем картинки...");

        try
        {
            int i = 1;
            BitmapImage bImage = null;
            foreach (var address in addresses)
            {
                //to UI
                MessageUser.MessageJob.Report($"Загружаем {i}...");
                //новая картинка
                bImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(address, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                //размеры
                bImage.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
                bImage.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
                //картинку в коллекцию
                ListImages.Add(bImage);
                //счетчик
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(LoadListImages)} - {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Метод отрабатывает на ура. Я даже по шагам его проходил, и даже в ситуациях, когда возникает эта ошибка, но ошибка возникает сразу после выхода из метода, т.е., как я понимаю, в момент когда уже UI должен начать отображать картинки и `BitmapImage` начинает "подгружать" по нужной ссылке. Как можно это побороть?

Comment: Памяти хватает? Как ListImages привязан к ListBox, там ничего не нужно очищать?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов на старте программа занимает ок.100Мб, после сбора ссылок ок. 135Мб, если не возникает этой ошибки, и картинки загрузились, то ок.350Мб. Очищать ничего не надо, т.к. `ListImages = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();`

Comment: И все же перед загрузкой (поскольку дефект плавающий) я бы сделал ListImages.Cleare() и GC.Collect(). По коду, который Вы привели, я не вижу ничего другого криминального

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась некоторым переписыванием в асинхронном стиле, плюс отказ от прямой загрузки картинки по адресу с помощью самого `BitmapImage`, а задействование для этого `HttpClient`. Ну и в целом картинки стали появляться (загружаться) постепенно одна за одной, а не скопом сразу как это было раньше.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Заполнение списка картинок
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="addresses"></param>
    private async Task LoadListImagesAsync(List<string> addresses)
    {
        //будущая коллекция картинок
        ListImages = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

        //to UI
        MessageUser.MessageJob.Report("Загружаем картинки...");

        //общее количество загружаемых картинок
        string count = addresses.Count.ToString();

        try
        {

            int i = 1;
            BitmapImage bImage = null;
            foreach (var address in addresses)
            {
                //to UI
                MessageUser.MessageJob.Report($"Загружаем: {i} из {count}...");
                //новая картинка
                Uri pathPicture = new Uri(address, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                bImage = await LoadBitmapImageAsync(pathPicture);
                //картинку в коллекцию
                ListImages.Add(bImage);
                //счетчик
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(LoadListImagesAsync)} - {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загрузка картинки из адреса
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pathPicture">адрес картинки</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<BitmapImage> LoadBitmapImageAsync(Uri pathPicture)
    {
        BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
        //размеры
        result.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
        result.DecodePixelWidth = 100;

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(pathPicture))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                result.BeginInit();
                result.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                result.StreamSource = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                result.EndInit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(LoadBitmapImageAsync)} - {ex.Message}");
            return new BitmapImage();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Ну, асинхронную одновременную загрузку можно сделать и с async/await

Comment: @VladD, видимо я несколько поторопился с выводами... Сейчас еще потестил и в Diagnostic Tools в Events обнаружил периодическое появление разных ошибок связанных именно с загрузкой из интернета, видимо все-таки некоторые сайты плохо загружаются или вообще не отдают картинки. Но зато приложение хотя бы не падает, а вместо ошибочной картинки белое поле остается. Меня это устраивает пока.

Comment: По поводу асинхронной загрузки, как-то так: http://pastebin.com/VM34nE1f

Comment: @VladD ага, спасибо